# How to find how many numbers are in q given range

Tags: python, list

That's what I have tried:

```
def between(lst, a, b):
    for i in lst:
        count = 0
        if a < i < b:
            count+=1 
    return count
```

Comment: You just have to set `count = 0` before the `for i in lst` loop, not inside the loop. Otherwise it gets set to 0 for each new `i`.

Comment: and decide whether you want to include or exclude the elements of your list that are exactly equal to `a` and `b`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I'd be happy if someone could tell me what I was wrong with, or be able to send a solution" This isn't a discussion forum, and we require a specific *question* as described in [ask]. You should start by explaining *what happened when you tried using your code*, and *how that is different from what is supposed to happen*, and then ask a question (using a question word at the start and a `?` at the end) that explains your *specific* difficulty in solving the problem. You should also show us what you've tried so far in order to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Why was this closed as "not reproducible"? I can tell the problem is still present by just looking at the code

Comment: @Neuron I'm assuming that it was considered a typo - putting the `count = 0` line in the wrong place. Not sure, though, as I'm not one of the close voters.

Comment: @AdrianMole you are right, that is likely. Although its clearly not a typo, but just a beginner trying to wrap their head around programming

Comment: @Neuron It's a common occurrence - I'm not really a Pythonista, but I'll accept your 'argument' and throw in the final reopen vote! (We get a lot of these closures in C and C++, where `==` and `=` get muddled: is it a typo or a misunderstanding? Either way, one can argue for "solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." if you want to be finnicky.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you reset `count` to 0 for every element in the list.

```
def between(lst, a, b):
    count = 0
    for i in lst: 
        if a < i < b:
            count+=1 
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `len` and a comprehension as well and not even have to have `count` to worry about:

```
def between(lst, a, b):
    return len(i for i in lst if a < i < b)
```

Comment: while this is a nice solution, I doubt OP is at the point where this will be helpful, rather than utterly confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your range validation needs to be inclusive. Try this:

```
def count_items_in_range(iterable: list, left_limit: float, right_limit: float) -> int:
    count: int = 0

    for item in iterable:
        if left_limit <= item <= right_limit:
            count+=1 

    return count
```